# How to get key value under a key?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use the spinner to display the key which under specific username but unfortunately it returns nothing to the spinner. I used an array to store the key value which under the username.
Here's my database structure

[image: Database structure]

Let's said I am rexyou0831 and I just want to retrieve the 2 usernames which under my username but my code return me nothing to the list. un is my current username variables. Please if you got any idea please share it with me thank you.

Hers' my code

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
cref = db.getReference("chat");

 public ArrayList<String> retrieve()
{
    final ArrayList<String> Student=new ArrayList<>();
    cref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot c:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {

                if(c.getKey().equals(un)){

                    for(DataSnapshot d: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        Student.add(d.getKey());

                    }

                }else{

                    Student.clear();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return Student;
}
```

Comment: what is `un` inside loop

Comment: firebase `Listener` is  asynchronous you need to set data in adapter after the loop finished

Comment: if under the "chat" got anykey equal username so un is the username.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get those usernames under your username, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("chat").child("rexyou0831");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String userName = ds.getKey();
            list.add(userName);
        }
        Log.d("TAG", list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your out put will be: [gigi1212, mario123]

Note, that `onDataChenge()` is called asynchronous which means that is called even before you are adding those keys to the list. As a conslusion, you need to declare and use that list, inside `onDataChenge()`, otherwise is `null`.

Comment: once again. Thank you alex.

Comment: @akhilesh0707 Thanks akhilesh0707!